# issue with node-opus installing

Tags: c++, node.js, npm, node-gyp

I have problem with installing node-opus on Windows 10 with:

- Visual studio 2015 with windows 10 and windows 8.1 sdk and tools + C++;
- npm v. 3.8.5;
- python 2.7;

When I tried to install my node-opus in my project it says me build error:

```
> ref@1.3.2 install F:\node-js-app\bots\ContentBot\node_modules\ref
> node-gyp rebuild


F:\node-js-app\bots\ContentBot\node_modules\ref>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_m
odules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  binding.cc
..\src\binding.cc(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node.h': No such file or directory [F:\node-js-app\
bots\ContentBot\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:2
76:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node
-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd F:\node-js-app\bots\ContentBot\node_modules\ref
gyp ERR! node -v v5.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
contentbot@0.0.1 F:\node-js-app\bots\ContentBot
+-- discord.js@6.1.0
+-- request@2.69.0
`-- socket.io@1.4.5

npm WARN contentbot@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "ins
tall" "node-opus"
npm ERR! node v5.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! ref@1.3.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ref@1.3.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ref package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ref
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ref
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     F:\node-js-app\bots\ContentBot\npm-debug.log
```

I also tried everything set environment variables, reinstall visual studio 2015, change locale langauge, reseting user profile to ascii name etc. Can someone pls help me?

Comment: Try to install node development files with `node-gyp install` command. You  can also list installed dev. files with `node-gyp list` command.